# Little sound comes out of my audio output jack.

Tags: 12.04, sound, dell

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 17r. I believe this is a known bug,"https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/994685", but I may be wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the best thing to do is to go into `alsamixer` (via terminal) and boost the sound of the "Speaker" volume. Don't know why this is so, it's dumb, but it works... until you plug a new audio device in.